# при вставке изображения на сайт с прозрачным фоном (png) вместе с изображением появляется белый фон вокруг него? как убрать его

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
как сделать чтобы отображалось только облако на фоне неба?

Comment: Там нет прозрачного фона на изображении с облаком. Скорее всего, файл был неправильно сохранен, если его редактировали.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpeJc.jpg

Comment: @andreymal спасибо. возможно это и была причина проблемы)

Comment: @void спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости как было сохранено это изображение, этот "шахматный" фон можно убрать  при помощи Photoshop.
Вот линк на видео с примерами как можно удалить этот задний фон:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FIYgibZazY
Автор данного видео показывает 2 способа как можно удалить "шахматный" фон у картинки. Все зависит от того как изображение было создано и в зависимости от этого применяется один из способ удаления "шахматного " фона у картинки.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)